# Checking Virtuoso version via SPARQL

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

Is there any way to check the version of `Virtuoso` in `SPARQL`, not by going to the server as an admin? Sort of like in Postgres, you would do `select version()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [documented on OpenLink's website](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtCheckSvrVersionViaSparql) --

You can leverage Virtuoso's built-in-functions, such as `sys_stat`, and the associated `bif:` SPARQL prefix, to use SPARQL to interrogate the server for various details, such as --

```
SELECT
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_dbms_name')          AS ?name )
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_dbms_ver')           AS ?version )
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_build_thread_model') AS ?thread )
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_build_opsys_id')     AS ?opsys )
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_build_date')         AS ?date )
      ( bif:sys_stat('git_head')              AS ?git_head )   
    # ( bif:sys_stat('st_lic_owner')          AS ?owner )
    # ( bif:sys_stat('st_lic_serial_number')  AS ?serial )
    
WHERE
      {  ?s  ?p  ?o  }
LIMIT 1
```

The `st_lic_owner` and `st_lic_serial_number` arguments are only valid on the Commercial Edition, and will produce a SPARQL error on the Open Source Edition; hence, they're commented out here.

The `git_head` argument is necessary to nail down the specific codebase revision from which the binary was built.  It is not available if the binary was built from a ZIP or TGZ archive downloaded from GitHub; a `git clone` or similar must have been used.

The above SPARQL query can also be run through an SQL interface (iSQL, ODBC, JDBC, etc.) by prepending the `SPARQL` keyword, and appending the `;` SQL query terminator, as below --

```sql
SPARQL
SELECT
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_dbms_name')          AS ?name )
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_dbms_ver')           AS ?version )
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_build_thread_model') AS ?thread )
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_build_opsys_id')     AS ?opsys )
      ( bif:sys_stat('st_build_date')         AS ?date )
      ( bif:sys_stat('git_head')              AS ?git_head )   
    # ( bif:sys_stat('st_lic_owner')          AS ?owner )
    # ( bif:sys_stat('st_lic_serial_number')  AS ?serial )
    
WHERE
      {  ?s  ?p  ?o  }
LIMIT 1 ;
```